# How to write the statement using Mathematical notation?

Tags: logic

"No integer greater than 40 can be written as the sum of 3 integers less than 20."

I'm having issues with the "3 integers less than 20" part

Comment: $\lnot \exists n,m,p \ (n < 20 \land m < 20 \land p < 20)$

Comment: What you wrote is perfectly clear and unambiguous. I don't think any "mathematical notation" is necessary, here. The purpose of mathematical writing is clarity, not to fill the page with strange squiggles and jargon.

Comment: "No integer $n>40$ can be written as $n=a+b+c$ with $a,b,c<20$." This is false, of course. Consider this statement: "No integer greater than $40$ can be written as the sum of $3$ cubes less than $20$".

Comment: I am aware of this. But a question asks to write the statement using mathematical notation only.